# c++: накопление данных в гистограмме (оптимизация по памяти и произвольности)

Tags: c++, c++11, map, контейнеры, unordered-map

Стоит следующая задача:

Заполняется гистограмма, при этом кол-во каналов произвольно (заранее неизвестно), т.е. выполняется операция

```
hist.add(channel_id, value)
```

требуется выполнять данную операцию быстро и при этом, чтобы гистограмма потребляла не очень много памяти

Когда стояла задача только в скорости заполнения гистограммы, то делал следующим образом:

```
using hist_t = std::map<int, int>;

hist_t hist;

// найти информацию о канале
hist_t::iterator point = hist.find(channel_id);

// если точка найдена - обновить данные иначе добавить новую точку
if (point != hist.end())
    point->second += value;
else
    hist.insert(hist_pr(channel_id, value));
```

Затем вместо `std::map` стал использовать `std::unordered_map`.

Но когда появилась надобность использовать (заполнять) очень много гистограмм с большим кол-вом каналов то стал вопрос и используемой памяти.

Подскажите, можно ли как-то и рыбку съесть и на лошадке покататься? Т.е. чтобы гистограмма заполнялась быстро, но при этом и память расходовалась умеренно (все таки `map` и `unordered_map` ее используют излишне)

P.S.

как понимаю в качестве одной из оптимизаций можно вместо

```
hist.insert(hist_pr(channel_id, value));
```

использовать

```
hist.emplace(channel_id, value);
```

что должно при создании нового канала чуть-чуть помочь (хотя это капля в море, поскольку чаще всего данные добавляются в уже существующие каналы)

Comment: а channel_id это что? какой у него формат-диапазон?

Comment: @KoVadim, каждый канал состоит из индекса и значения - `std:pair<int, int>`, можно было бы использовать вектор `std::vector<int>`, но памяти это будет жрать много (например если будет только 2 канала - 0й и 1000й - для вектора это будет означать создание 1000 элементов, из которых 998 будет нулевыми, поэтому лучше использовать словарь, с другой стороны (для памяти) лучше словаря каналов лучше использовать вектор каналов `std::vector<hist_pr>`, где hist_pr - `std:pair<int, int>`, но очень медленное будет добавление данных (а добавление - это самая частая операция).

Comment: А уже профилировали или это "так кажется"

Comment: @KoVadim, да, профайлером прогонял, да и на реальных задачах уже использовал, поэтому и думаю усиленно что можно сделать - потому что когда несколько суток работает и память вся съедена - это не очень хорошо :(, но с другой стороны и задачи тяжелые. Поэтому и подумалось - может есть что-то, что не учел - другая организация контейнеров, но даже в теории - хочешь быстро пахать - нужен бинарный поиск, а это словари, но за словари плати дополнительной памятью (порядка ~20 байт на элемент), еще круче O(1) - дает фиксированный массив, то там расход памяти вообще дикий из-за неиспользуемых элементов

Comment: вот поэтому я и спросил о том, какой диапазон и характер channel_id, а Вы начали мне рассказывать известные вещи.  В целом, std::map очень не дружелюбен к памяти, если в него постоянно пишут/удаляют (фрагментирование).

Comment: @KoVadim, что же лучше использовать?

Comment: Вы читаете мой вопрос или нет? Не зная исходных данных, сложно что то предлагать

Comment: @KoVadim, исходные данные как я писал выше - совокупность точек с целочисленными координатами `(x, y)`. На вход подается огромный массив пар `(x_src, y_src)`, для каждой такой пары находится в совокупности точек точка с координатой `x` равная `x_src` и ее значение `y` увеличивается на значение `y_src` (т.е. строится некоторое распределение/гистограмма). если ранее такой точки не было - она добавляется (это и было показано в коде). Все.

Comment: Я уже третий раз спрашиваю, какие возможные значение у channel_id? Пока я только увидел предположение, что там может быть 1 и 1000. Но не более. А Вы продолжаете отвечать на свои вопросы.

Comment: @KoVadim, все, теперь понял :) номер канала от 0 до 2^32 (но чаще всего до нескольких миллионов), значение в каждом канале также от 0 до 2^32 (тут и до миллиарда легко дотягивается и даже на __int64 поглядываю, потому что за 4 миллиарда может перевалить значение), всего каналов обычно несколько тысяч (т.е. может быть так: канал 0 значение 11, канал 134 значение 767622, канал 350923 значение 5). И таких гистограмм до сотни тысяч за раз (конечно можно сделать последовательное заполнение, но это будет приводить к повторному считыванию терабайтных файлов)

Comment: я понял, это тестовая задача и номера каналов просто равномерно-случайно распределены. Тогда нужно придумать хорошую хеш функцию и будет хорошо.